# How to fix segment Fault Error in Terminal?

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

[Output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1xyk.png)

I'm trying to compile my code and I feel it works perfectly fine and I can get it to compile. However, when I do I'm getting Segment fault error and I don't see where the error is in my code.

The error i'm getting is Segment fault: 11 
I've looked this up and I know it has to do with memory allocation but haven't been able to find where in the code do I need to fix my memory allocation and fix the errors I have on here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*The Main Function Start*/
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /*Storing The Process Id*/
    pid_t pid;
    int j;
    int status = 0;


    /*process of forking*/

    if (argc == 1){
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: ./hw1 <starting value>\n");
    }
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    pid=fork();
    if (pid == -1){
        printf("Error in forking....\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    /*Child process*/
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        printf("Child PID: %d\n",getpid());

        while (n != 1){
            printf("%d ",n);
            if (n % 2 == 0){
                n = n/2;
            }
            else {
                n = 3*n + 1;
            }

        }
        printf("1\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Parent PID: %d\n",getpid());
        /*Waiting for the child to finish*/
        wait(0);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You get a `segfault` when you call it without any arguments, because you didn't `exit` or `return` after printing to `stderr`. The `atoi(argv[1])` is problem because of what I said before.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of the output from the terminal, just copy & paste the output from terminal and post it in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only get a segfault when I'm not passing any parameters, because

```
int n = atoi(argv[1]);
```

would be doing essentially `atoi(NULL)`, because `argv[1]` would be `NULL`.

```
if (argc != 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <starting value>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1; // <- you forgot this!
}
```

Calling your program with different values doesn't lead to a segfault, I've
tried it with different numbers.

Another error: the `main` function should be defined as:

- `int main(void);`
- `int main(int argc, char *argv[]);`
- `int main(int argc, char **argv);`

You should change that. See [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

For general information. If you want to exit a `void` function, all you have
to do is use `return;` without any value, like this:

```
void foo(void)
{
    do_some_work();

    if(should_i_terminate)
        return;

    keep_doing_work();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this now

Comment: void function 'main' should not return a value

Comment: @black `main` should not be `void`, I've missed that error.

Comment: @black: See [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) for the sordid details.   In general, `void main()` is a bug.

Comment: Thanks I fixed that but the program isn't producing the child as intende.d

Comment: Slightly more solid would be `if (argc != 2)`

Comment: @black That's another problem that has nothing to do with the segfault. You haven't told us what the child should do/print, I don't know the algorith, so I cannot see any error. I merely answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it to work but it's not printing the child. It just exits right after starting value

Comment: Program should also display the process IDs of both the parent and child process

Comment: @black what does *right after starting value* mean? The child is behaving accordingly to your code: it enters, calculates some values and prints them, when the value is 1 it exists the loop, prints 1, and then there's nothing more to do `exit(0)` is executed. What else did you expect?

Comment: @black it does. I executed your program with the value 3: `./b 3`, the output is `Parent PID: 13630 Child PID: 13631  3 10 5 16 8 4 2 1`.

Comment: Sorry i'm kinda new to programming. I just uploaded the output of my code. I want it to print the process ID of both parent and child.

Comment: I'm soooo stupid. I just ran it without putting any number in.